# CAS Server 3.4.10 on tomcat.. where is user information

Tags: authentication, cas

I am trying to learn CAS and I have the cas-server-3.4.10 running in tomcat6 by just moving the war into the webapp.. I am following the install.txt which show me to use NetID for the user name and password and it works but where is the user information?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the standard WAR file without making any changes, the default authentication handlers works such that the userId must be the same as the password you put in, so that you can login. This is just a sample and should never really be used in production.

Your user credential store is usually maintained elsewhere, typically inside an LDAP or ActiveDirectory instance. You'll then need to configure the config file with the right authentication handler that received the connection info to that instance and validates user accounts.

CAS is not responsible for user account management, etc. It works with existing solutions that provide a remedy for that need.